# Selecting specific data based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlcommand

I need some help constructing a SQL command for a database query. The database has 5 columns:

```
Date(string) 
Name(string) 
number(int)
```

There can be multiple entries for each date, name, and number.

I want to SELECT only one row for each date and name combination. The problem is there are multiple instances of these.  For each date and name combination I want to select the one with the highest number. I would like it ordered by date. For example:

```
date   |  name  |  number
1/1/1     henry      500
1/1/1     henry      2000 
1/1/1     jacob      5
1/1/1     jacob      8
1/2/1     henry      6
```

The command would return:

```
1/1/1     henry     2000
1/1/1     jacob     8 
1/2/1     henry     6
```

I have been messing around with some commands but I am a pretty lost. Is this even possible?

Comment: What SQL flavor (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) are you using?  What have you already tried?  Do you know how to use `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Yes I do. I think I see where you're going with that. I will give it a shot.

Comment: I posted what I had in mind. If you had other columns that you needed to see then the solution would not be that simple as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT date, 
                name, 
                number, 
                rn = Row_number () 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY date, name 
                         ORDER BY number DESC) 
         FROM   dbo.tablename) 
SELECT date, 
       name, 
       number 
FROM CTE
WHERE  rn = 1 
ORDER  BY date ASC
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4e5a/2/0)

`ROW_NUMBER` will always select one record per group. If you want to get all rows with the highest number for a given name(if there are more than one) use `DENSE_RANK` instead.

Comment: Thank you. However I am not sure I understand the WITH cte... can this be used in SQL Server?

Comment: @40Alpha: Yes, that's TSQL which works in MS SQL-Server. It uses a [`Common Table Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) + [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) (which also exists in other rdbms like Oracle). I've used the CTE for simplification since they increase readability.

Comment: Makes sense now haha! Thank you. I will let you know if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by date and name and then selecting the maximum number.  Like so (exact syntax may vary depending on your version of sql):

```
select
   date,
   name,
   max(number)
from
   yourtable
group by
   date,
   name
order by
   date asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, name, MAX(number)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY date, name
ORDER date, name
```